# Java: Inherit constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to have a constructor with an argument that gets inherited by all child classes automatically, but Java won't let me do this

```java
class A {
    public A(int x) {
     // Shared code here
    }
}

class B extends A {
    // Implicit (int x) constructor from A
}

class C extends A {
    // Implicit (int x) constructor from A
}
```

I don't want to have to write `B(int x)`, `C(int x)`, etc. for each child class. Is there a smarter way of approaching this problem?

Solution #1. Make an `init()` method that can be called after the constructor. This works, although for my particular design, I want to require the user to specify certain parameters in the constructor that are validated at compile time (e.g. Not through varargs/reflection).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't. If you want to have a parameterized constructor in your base class - and no no-argument constructor - you will have to define a constructor (and call `super()` constructor) in each of descendant classes.

Comment: No matter how many times I am reminded of this, it's still upsetting.  Put in all this effort to make comprehensive base classes, then the children end up as 50 liners because I have to overwrite so much boilerplate

Answer (score 13):

The other replies are correct that Java won't let you inherit constructors.  But IDEs can be used to help ease the massive burden of creating these for all your classes.

In Eclipse go to the "Source" menu and select "Generate Contructors from Superclass...".  You can also select this as an option when using the dialog to create a new class.

Comment: Hmmm ... one person's "massive burden" is another person's trivial task.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, you can Alt+Insert and choose Constructor. That will bring up a menu where you can choose one or more parent constructors to implement, and those will get created automatically.

Answer (score 4):

[Inheritance](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

> SUMMARY: A subclass inherits all the
>   members (fields, methods, and nested
>   classes) from its superclass.
>   Constructors are not members, so they
>   are not inherited by subclasses, but
>   the constructor of the superclass can
>   be invoked from the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in java. You can't give a method arguments without explicitly declaring them in the method. Doing this probably wouldn't be the best idea, it could lead to very confusing code and over-complicate things. The alternative of having to type a few extra characters isn't *that* bad. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default value you want to assign you could create an empty constructor in the base class that calls the parameterized constructor.

This would remove the need to child classes to call the parameterized constructors.